# ngGrid wont display properly

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I'm working with bower (json file below).

I'm failing to initiate simple ngGrid. It's so simple (ng grid is awesome i must say) that i don't know what i'm doing wrong.

index.jade:

```
div(ng-controller='Ctrl')
    div(style="border: 1px solid rgb(212,212,212); width : 400px; height: 300px", ng-grid='gridOptions')
```

controller.coffee:

```
'use strict'

angular.module('client.controllers', [])

.controller('Ctrl', [
'$log'
'$scope'

($log, $scope) ->
  $scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'myData'
    enablePinning: true
    columnDefs: [
      { field: "name", width: 120, pinned: true },
      { field: "age", width: 120 },
      { field: "birthday", width: 120 },
      { field: "salary", width: 120 }
    ]
  }

  $scope.myData = [
    { name: "Moroni", age: 50, birthday: "Oct 28, 1970", salary: "60,000" }
    { name: "Tiancum", age: 43, birthday: "Feb 12, 1985", salary: "70,000" }
    { name: "Jacob", age: 27, birthday: "Aug 23, 1983", salary: "50,000" }
    { name: "Nephi", age: 29, birthday: "May 31, 2010", salary: "40,000" }
    { name: "Enos", age: 34, birthday: "Aug 3, 2008", salary: "30,000" }
    { name: "Moroni", age: 50, birthday: "Oct 28, 1970", salary: "60,000" }
    { name: "Tiancum", age: 43, birthday: "Feb 12, 1985", salary: "70,000" }
    { name: "Jacob", age: 27, birthday: "Aug 23, 1983", salary: "40,000" }
    { name: "Nephi", age: 29, birthday: "May 31, 2010", salary: "50,000" }
    { name: "Enos", age: 34, birthday: "Aug 3, 2008", salary: "30,000" }
    { name: "Moroni", age: 50, birthday: "Oct 28, 1970", salary: "60,000" }
    { name: "Tiancum", age: 43, birthday: "Feb 12, 1985", salary: "70,000" }
    { name: "Jacob", age: 27, birthday: "Aug 23, 1983", salary: "40,000" }
    { name: "Nephi", age: 29, birthday: "May 31, 2010", salary: "50,000" }
    { name: "Enos", age: 34, birthday: "Aug 3, 2008", salary: "30,000" }
  ]
])
```

and what i'm getting is:

[image]

bower json:

```
{
"name": "main",
"version": "0.0.0",
"authors": [
    "gumba"
],
"license": "MIT",
"ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "test",
    "tests"
],
"dependencies": {
    "querystring":"*",
    "angular": "*",
    "angular-sanitize": "*",
    "angular-resource": "*",
    "angular-route": "*",
    "angular-cookies": "*",
    "angular-mocks": "*",
    "bootstrap": "*",
    "sugarjs": "*",
    "datatables":"*",
    "ng-grid":"*"
}
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you removed pinned:true? Also note that your defined width of the containing DIV is smaller than the width of all the cols combined, if that makes a difference.

Comment: I tried to remove the pinned property, doesn't make the change. The width calculations is in purpose (to use the pinned feature)

Comment: You can try using the new uiGrid instead. I'm using that without any issues like you are seeing. It kind of looks like maybe a CSS related issue. I would check the various styles and fiddle around with them in  the debugger of whatever browser you are using

Comment: Yes i'm aware of ui-grid. But note that ui-grid team wrote in their [git page](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid) that they aren't ready for production (it's still pre-beta).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgrading ng-grid from 2.0.14 to 2.0.11 did the job for me. 
I guess it's just some backwards compatibility issue that will be solved in later versions so nothing interesting here.